How to solve com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None) for multithreaded excel application?
I have a worker thread for a PYQT5 application that feeds into a progress bar when the function is called. The issue is that I am getting a com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None) whenever I call the excel function. How can I fix this error?
I created the following Worker class and progress bar class which calls the worker class. Here is an image of the UI

import sys
import time

from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication,QMainWindow, QWidget, QProgressBar,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, pyqtSlot
import win32com.client as win32


month="April"    
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
destination=rf"C:\Users\RC\Desktop\Important Emails\WIP Special Workings\FY2024\{month}"


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)
    @pyqtSlot()
    def proc_counter(self):
     count=0
     data_file = rf"C:\Users\RC\Desktop\Important Emails\WIP Special Workings\FY2024\{month}\gl transaction download-cc1.xlsx"
     template_file=rf"C:\Users\RC\Desktop\Important Emails\WIP Special Workings\FY2024\{month}\GL Dump - {month}.xlsx"
     wb_template = excel.Workbooks.Open(template_file)
     wb_data = excel.Workbooks.Open(data_file)
     count+=20
     self.intReady.emit(count)
     wb_template.Sheets("GL Data Jan").Range("A2:W5000").Clear()
     wb_data.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:W5000").Copy()
     wb_template.Sheets("GL Data Jan").Paste(wb_template.Sheets("GL Data Jan").Range('A2'))
     count+=20
     self.intReady.emit(count)
     wb_template.RefreshAll()
     time.sleep(3)
     count+=40
     self.intReady.emit(count)
     wb_template.Save()
     count+=19
     self.intReady.emit(count)
     wb_template.Close(True)
     wb_data.Close(True)
     excel.Application.Quit()
     count+=1
     self.intReady.emit(count)
     self.finished.emit()
     return None
            

            
    
class PopUpProgressB(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        #self.pbar.setRange(0,0)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 500, 75)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 550, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')

        self.obj = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.obj.intReady.connect(self.on_count_changed)
        
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
     
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.hide)  # To hide the progress bar after the progress is completed
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.proc_counter)
       

    def start_progress(self):
        # To restart the progress every time
        self.show()
        self.thread.start()

    def on_count_changed(self, value):
        self.pbar.setValue(value)

class Screen2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Screen2,self).__init__()
        loadUi("GL_Dump_Curr.ui",self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.gotoScreen1)
        self.popup=PopUpProgressB()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.popup.start_progress)


I used multiprocessing and it worked now, finally, after so long.
from multiprocessing import Process

class PopUpProgressB(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        #self.pbar.setRange(0,0)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 500, 75)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 550, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')

        self.obj = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
       
        p1 = Process(target=self.obj.intReady.connect(self.on_count_changed), args=())
        p2= Process(target= self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.proc_counter), args=())
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.hide)  # To hide the progress bar after the progress is completed


Maybe the answer  to this other question is of help:
import pythoncom


def onThreadStart(threadIndex):
  pythoncom.CoInitialize()

cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start_thread', onThreadStart)


It’s still not working, the error keeps coming up

@RaphCar If you move the Excel object creation code to inside the thread code, does it work (with the pythoncom.CoInitialize() call which you will still need)? It is possibly an issue around the COM model being used: by default (I think) you get the Apartment Model where every COM object lives within one thread, and you can have issues talking to that object from a different thread.

No, I tried this as well and the application wont open if i do that.
